# R fast way to perturb through data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame that I'm trying to do some scenario analysis with.  It looks like this:

```
Revenue     Item_1    Item_2    Item_3
 552          200       220       45
 1500         400       300       200
 2300         600       400       300
```

I'd like to generate something where 1 item is increased or decreased by some fixed amount (ie 1 unite) like this:

```
Revenue     Item_1    Item_2    Item_3
 552          201       220       45
 1500         401       300       200
 2300         601       400       300

 552          200       221       45
 1500         400       301       200
 2300         600       401       300

 552          200       220       46
 1500         400       300       201
 2300         600       400       301
```

I'm currently doing it in loop like this but am wondering if there's a faster way:

```
l1 <- list()
increment_amt <- 1
for(i in c('Item_1','Item_2','Item_3')){
   newDf <- df1
   newDf[,i] <- newDf[,i] + increment_amt
   l1[[i]] <- newDf
}

df2 <- do.call(rbind, l1)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `lapply`,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(dat)[2:4], function(x) {dat[,x] <- dat[,x] + 1; dat}))
  Revenue Item_1 Item_2 Item_3
1     552    201    220     45
2    1500    401    300    200
3    2300    601    400    300
4     552    200    221     45
5    1500    400    301    200
6    2300    600    401    300
7     552    200    220     46
8    1500    400    300    201
9    2300    600    400    301
```

Of course, `do.call / rbind` can be replaced with the `data.table`'s speedier `rbindlist`, which returns a data.table.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(names(dat)[2:4], function(x) {dat[,x] <- dat[,x] + 1; dat}))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a function and use `lapply` to achieve this task. `df` is your original data frame. `df_list` is a list with all final outputs. You can later use `df2 <- do.call(rbind, df_list)`, or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.

```
# A function to add 1 to all numbers in a column
add_one <- function(Col, dt){
  dt[, Col] <- dt[, Col] + 1
  return(dt)
}

# Get the column names
Col_vec <- colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)]

# Apply the add_one function
df_list <- lapply(Col_vec, add_one, dt = df)

# Combine all results
df2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Data frame
df <- data.frame(Item_1= c(200, 400, 600), 
                 Item_2= c(220, 300, 400), 
                 Item_3= c(45, 200, 300))

# Perturbation
p <- 1

# Add to all columns
df.new <- apply(diag(ncol(df)) * p, MAR = 1, function(x)data.frame(t(t(df) + x)))

[[1]]
  Item_1 Item_2 Item_3
1    201    220     45
2    401    300    200
3    601    400    300

[[2]]
  Item_1 Item_2 Item_3
1    200    221     45
2    400    301    200
3    600    401    300

[[3]]
  Item_1 Item_2 Item_3
1    200    220     46
2    400    300    201
3    600    400    301
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use perturb function in R using library(perturb). The code is as follows:

```
# using the most important features, we create a model
m1 <- lm(revenue ~  item1 + item2 + item3)
#summary(m1)
#anova(m1)
#install.packages("perturb")
library(perturb)
set.seed(1234)
p1_new <- perturb(m1, pvars=c("item1","item2") , prange = c(1,1),niter=20)
p1_new
summary(p1_new)
```